# scala turning an Iterator[Option[T]] into an Iterator[T]

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have an `Iterator[Option[T]]` and I want to get an `Iterator[T]` for those `Option`s where `T` `isDefined`. There must be a better way than this:

```
it filter { _ isDefined} map { _ get }
```

I would have thought that it was possible in one construct... Anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the case where `it` is an `Iterable`

```
val it:Iterable[Option[T]] = ...
it.flatMap( x => x )                //returns an Iterable[T]
```

In the case where `it` is an `Iterator`

```
val it:Iterator[Option[T]] = ...
it.flatMap( x => x elements )       //returns an Iterator[T]
it.flatMap( _ elements)             //equivalent
```

Comment: Knowing who you are (from the scala-user mailing list), you are right I'm sure (don't have access to my Scala dev envt at the moment :-). Can you explain a bit how this works. I promise I'm not an idiot but I have no idea how I would be supposed to get this from the scaladoc

Comment: Would it not be "it flatMap { _ elements }" ? (I've read the scaladoc again!)

Comment: It would be great to see more Scala gurus on StackOverflow. The scala-user mailing list is filling up my inbox with arcane arguments over break/continue :-)

Comment: As I see it, what you have to do is just flatten your iterable, but since Iterable doesn't have a flatten method, you use flatMap and the (x => x) simply means no actual mapping is required, you only get the effect of flattening. Still, I'd like to see a good explanation w/the scaladoc description.

Comment: Apologies. I've just noticed that the topic and body don't ask the same question. I answered the body rather than the topic. 

it.flatMap(x => x) will turn an Iterable[Option[T]] into an Iterable[T]. it.flatMap(_.elements) will turn an Iterator[Option[T]] into an Iterator[Option[T]].

Comment: What do you mean that the topic and body don't ask the same question? Yes they do...

Comment: No. The topic asks about an Iterator, the body asks about an Iterable.

Comment: Many apologies - I meant Iterator, not Iterable!

Answer (score 11):

In newer versions this is now possible:

```
val it: Iterator[Option[T]] = ...
val flatIt = it.flatten
```

Comment: Well yeah, NOW you would.  When the question was asked and answered, that didn't work.  (In case you can't tell, your use of the word "simple" carries the implication that the previous discussants managed to overlook the straightforward answer.)

Answer (score 5):

This works for me (Scala 2.8):

```
it.collect {case Some(s) => s}
```

Answer (score 3):

To me, this is a classic use case for the monadic UI.

```
for {
  opt <- iterable
  t   <- opt
} yield t
```

It's just sugar for the `flatMap` solution described above, and it produces identical bytecode. However, syntax matters, and I think one of the best times to use Scala's monadic `for` syntax is when you're working with `Option`, especially in conjunction with collections.

I think this formulation is considerably more readable, especially for those not very familiar with functional programming. I often try both the monadic and functional expressions of a loop and see which seems more straightforward. I think *flatMap* is hard name for most people to grok (and actually, calling it `>>=` makes more intuitive sense to me).